# Does the standard consider non-template members of template classes to be "templates" themselves?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Consider following code:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T> struct A
{
    static_assert(!std::is_same_v<int, T>);
};

template<typename T> struct B
{
    void foo()
    {
        A<int>{};
    }
};

int main() {}
```

It comes from [this question](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/915701/) on russian StackOverflow, which asks whether it's valid or not.

I attempted to reference this:

> #### [[temp.res]/8.1](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.res#8.1)
>
> <sup>8</sup> The validity of a template may be checked prior to any instantiation. [ Note: Knowing which names are type names allows the syntax of every template to be checked in this way. — end note ] **The program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required, if:**
>
> <sup>(8.1)</sup> — **no valid specialization can be generated for a template** or a substatement of a constexpr if statement within a template and the template is not instantiated, or
>
> ...

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

Since no valid specialization can be generated for `foo()`, I reasoned that the snippet is ill-formed, NDR.

But I was told `[temp.res]/8.1` doesn't apply since `foo()` itself isn't a template member function.

[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/templates#Templated_entity) calls non-template member functions of template classes "templated entities", but it seems to be unclear if they can be considered templates themselves.

Thus, the question is: Does the standard consider non-template members of template classes to be "templates" themselves?

Comment: [**\[temp\]/2**](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp#2) seems to suggest that a member function of a class template is a template, seeing as its definition is a *template-declaration*. The standard doesn't seem to formally define the term *template* other than by a syntax diagram of *template-declaration* in [**\[temp\]/1**](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp#1)

Comment: Isn't it related to what depends on template argument and what doesn't? `A<int>` is always the same thing, regardless of the template argument `T` given when `B` is instantiated. The compiler will be able to recognize that the above construct will fail. On the other hand if you would have `A<T>{}` then it becomes dependent on the template argument `T` (of `B`). The compiler will make no effort to recognize which values of `T` will fail and which will not, until an instantiation happens. It could be that *all* possible `T` values lead to an error.

Comment: An (admittedly non-normative) example in [**\[temp.mem.func\]/1**](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.mem.func#1) shows a class template with three member functions, and says that the code "declares three function templates". So at least the intent of the authors seems to be to treat member functions as templates.

Comment: Also for "a member of a class template is a template": [\[temp.names\]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp#names-5) [\[temp.dep\]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp#dep-1) [\[temp.dep.type\]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp#dep.type-8) [\[temp.explicit\]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp#explicit-6) [\[temp.fct.spec\]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp#fct.spec-2)

Comment: Against "a member of a class template is a template": [\[temp\]/9](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp#9) [\[temp.names\]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp#names-2) [\[temp.dep.expr\]/3.6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp#dep.expr-3.6) [\[temp.expl.spec\]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp#expl.spec-6)

Comment: Though you could certainly argue that the "against" instances list "a template" and "a member of a class template" separately just for clarity, though redundant.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is essentially [CWG issue 1253](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1253)

> **Generic non-template members**
>
> **Section**: 17.8  [temp.spec]     **Status**: drafting     **Submitter**: Nikolay Ivchenkov     **Date**: 2011-03-06
>
> Many statements in the Standard apply only to templates, for example,
>   17.7 [temp.res] paragraph 8:
>
> > If no valid specialization can be generated for a template definition,
> >     and that template is not instantiated, the template definition is
> >     ill-formed, no diagnostic required.
>
> This clearly should apply to non-template member functions of class
>   templates, not just to templates per se. Terminology should be
>   established to refer to these generic entities that are not actually
>   templates.

It appears to be still in drafting. But I'd argue, like the issue, that the code in the OP *should* be ill-formed NDR as well. Even if the member function is never used (and therefore its full definition is never instantiated), it still cannot be even hypothetically instantiated, which puts it under the category of errors [temp.res]/8 is meant to cover.

Comment: Doesn't the OP example fall under ("a hypothetical instantiation of a template immediately following its definition would be ill-formed due to a construct that does not depend on a template parameter)[http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.res#8.4]?

Comment: @CygnusX1 - The crux of the matter is whether or not the member falls under the definition of a template, for this paragraph to apply. It doesn't seem to be conclusive to me, and I think the CWG issue still being active supports this assertion.

Comment: I am not sure if the member itself is a template. However, `B` as a whole *is* a template and trying to instantiate `B` will lead to an error.

Comment: @CygnusX1 - No it won't necessarily. Non-virtual member function definitions of class templates aren't instantiated unless they are used.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I stand corrected. I learnd something new :)